React Web App data not rendering in table for IOS Devices
I've developed a React web application with a table component to display data. It works perfectly fine on Windows, macOS, and Android devices, but I'm encountering rendering issues specifically on iOS devices.
On iOS devices, the table data seems to be partially rendered or not rendered at all. This inconsistency is puzzling because the same codebase renders the table perfectly on other platforms. I've ensured that there are no syntax errors or device-specific code blocks that could be causing this issue.
        <div key={1} ref={tableRef}>
          {/* CSV download button for entire report */}

          {financeData?.map((payPeriod, payIndex) => {
            let grandTotal = 0;
            let perDiemTotalAll = 0;
            let payRateTotalAll = 0;

            return (
              <div
                key={payIndex - payPeriod}
                className="mt-12 shadow-sm border rounded-lg overflow-x-auto "
              >
                <div
                  key={2}
                  className="bg-gray-50 text-gray-600 font-medium py-3 px-6 mb-3 "
                >
                  <p className="pl-6 py-3">
                    Pay Period Start: {formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodStart)} |
                    Pay Period End: {formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodEnd)} | Pay
                    Date: {formatDate(payPeriod.payDataPeriod)}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <table className="w-full table-auto text-sm text-left">
                  <thead className="bg-gray-50 text-gray-600 font-medium border-b">
                    <tr>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Nickname</th>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Item Detail</th>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Show</th>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Pay Rate</th>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Per Diem</th>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Work Days</th>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Catering (Days)</th>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Per Diem Total</th>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Pay Rate Total</th>
                      <th className="py-3 px-6">Final Pay</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody className="text-gray-600 divide-y">
                    {nickPayData?.flatMap((item, index) => {
                      const relevantROS = item?.ros.filter((rosItem) => {
                        const rosStartDate = new Date(
                          formatDate2(rosItem.startDate)
                        );
                        const rosEndDate = new Date(
                          formatDate2(rosItem.endDate)
                        );
                        return (
                          rosStartDate <=
                            new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodEnd)) &&
                          rosEndDate >=
                            new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodStart))
                        );
                      });

                      return relevantROS?.map((rosItem, rosIndex) => {
                        const startDate = new Date(
                          formatDate2(rosItem.startDate)
                        );
                        const endDate = new Date(formatDate2(rosItem.endDate));

                        // Calculate work days within the current pay period
                        const workDays = calculateWorkDays(
                          startDate <
                            new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodStart))
                            ? new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodStart))
                            : startDate, // Adjust start date if it falls before pay period start
                          endDate > new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodEnd))
                            ? new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodEnd))
                            : endDate // Adjust end date if it falls after pay period end
                        );
                        // Initialize catering days for start and end date
                        // let cateringDays = 0;

                        const cateringDays = calculateCateringDays(
                          startDate <=
                            new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodStart))
                            ? new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodStart))
                            : startDate, // Adjust start date if it falls before pay period start
                          endDate >=
                            new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodEnd))
                            ? new Date(formatDate(payPeriod.payPeriodEnd))
                            : endDate, // Adjust end date if it falls after pay period end
                          catering,
                          rosItem
                        );

                        const payRate =
                          rosItem?.itemDetail === "CS - SHOW DAY - OFF" ||
                          rosItem?.itemDetail === "CS - OFF UN-SCHEDULED"
                            ? 0
                            : calcPayRate(
                                parseInt(
                                  item?.payRate?.replace("$", "").trim()
                                ),
                                rosItem.itemDetail
                              );
                        const finalPay = calculateFinalPay(
                          payRate,
                          workDays,
                          cateringDays,
                          rosItem?.itemDetail
                        );
                        const perDiemTotal =
                          rosItem?.itemDetail === "CS - SHOW DAY - OFF" ||
                          rosItem?.itemDetail === "CS - OFF UN-SCHEDULED"
                            ? 0
                            : (workDays - cateringDays) *
                              parseInt(item?.perDiem?.replace("$", "").trim());
                        const payRateTotal = payRate * workDays;

                        // Accumulate totals
                        grandTotal += finalPay;
                        perDiemTotalAll += perDiemTotal;
                        payRateTotalAll += payRateTotal;

                        return (
                          <tr key={`${index}-${payIndex}-${rosIndex}`}>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              {item?.nickname}
                            </td>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              {rosItem?.itemDetail}
                            </td>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              {rosItem?.show}
                            </td>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              {item?.payRate}
                            </td>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              {item?.perDiem}
                            </td>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              {workDays}
                            </td>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              {cateringDays}
                            </td>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              ${perDiemTotal}
                            </td>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              ${payRateTotal}
                            </td>
                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                              ${finalPay}
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        );
                      });
                    })}

                    {/* Render Grand Total row */}
                    <tr>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold">
                        Grand Total
                      </td>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold"></td>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold"></td>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold"></td>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold"></td>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold"></td>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold"></td>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold">
                        ${perDiemTotalAll}
                      </td>
                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold">
                        ${payRateTotalAll}
                      </td>

                      <td className="px-6 py-4 w-full font-semibold">
                        ${grandTotal}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>```


Tested on Different iOS Versions: Confirmed that the issue persists across various iOS versions, ruling out the possibility of it being version-specific.

Looked for Known Issues: Searched through React and iOS development forums to see if others have encountered similar problems, but couldn't find any relevant solutions.


Hey did you ever find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same issue currently..

Yes, calculate all the data in your backend and then use in table directly it will work.

Not sure I understand, can you pleas elaborate. My issue specifically is that the content that requires scrolling to view is not shown on iOS. But works on other devices. Was that the same thing you saw?
